# How do I return movieclip to original size?

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

I made a gallery in flash. I have external images load in a fixed display area -- I call it 'imageStage'. When the image is loaded, I resize the movieclip at the _x and _y to make the image fit the stage.

But what happens -- when I flip prev/next through a couple images, they keep shrinking and shrinking. Images that are smaller than the fixed area are being shrunk even further.

How can I fix this? I'm thinking maybe if I clear the existing image from the MovieClip, it will reset itself back to regular size and proportions. But I don't know how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Found solution. To resize image, use _yscale and _xscale instead of _width and _height.

Answer (score 0):

That's only if you are adjusting it by those parameters.

What has worked for me quote often is that when a movie clip enters the stage, I record it's height/width/scale/x/y inside some container vars.

Depending on how the reset is triggered, just restore your movie clip using the values you stored.